# fscanf not reading from the beginning of text file

Tags: c

I am writing a program that reads virtual addresses (32 bit) integers from file and converts them to physical address. right now i am using fscanf to read each 32-bit integer from file. For some reason its not reading from the beginning of the text file. its starts reading from like the middle of the file.

e.g if you have the following numbers in file

```
16916
62493
30198
53683
40185
28781
24462
48399
64815
18295
12218
22760
57982
27966
54894
38929
```

it starts from like 18295. Intuitively i thought using fseek to set the pointer at the top would resolve it but it didn't.

My code please help.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char FileName[100];
    unsigned int LogicalAdd;
    FILE *fp; // file pointer
    unsigned int Offset;
    int AmountRead = 0;
    int FirstTime =0;

    fp = fopen("addresses.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
            printf("Error: couldn't open file");
    }

    while((fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &LogicalAdd)) == 1){
            printf("%d\n", LogicalAdd);
    }       
}
```

Comment: I don't see that code exhibiting the issue you describe.Is this your real code? If so, what is the purpose of `Offset`, `AmountRead`, and `FirstTime` that aren't used. What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: You can check using fgetc(char) function to check from where it starts reading. Do it for 2-3 times so u can know from where it starts .

Comment: Off topic: you need to do something more than just printing error messge if fopen fails. Specifically you should not continue to `fscanf` using `fp` if `fopen` fails.

Comment: @Dylan, that's a text file so surely each line is six bytes (five digits plus `\n`).

Comment: For what it's worth, your code doesn't show any issue [here](http://ideone.com/A9ikb6) if the file pointer is replaced with `stdin`.  I suspect there is something wrong with the file itself.

Comment: Thanks Ken please ignore the unused variables i will use them later. This is just the first step of a big program. My debugger doesn't work.

Comment: You guys can try it out with the file. Here is the link. https://blackboard.uwindsor.ca/bbcswebdav/pid-398568-dt-content-rid-1526600_1/courses/135370/addresses.txt

Comment: You use the wrong type specifier in the format string. Any modern compiler should warn. Warnings are not just for fun

Comment: Hi Paul can you please try it with all the input from this file. https://blackboard.uwindsor.ca/bbcswebdav/pid-398568-dt-content-rid-1526600_1/courses/135370/addresses.txt

Comment: This is no debugging service. See [ask].

Comment: @Olaf While `%d` is indeed not `%u` that's unlikely to cause problems with the quoted data on any *modern compiler*.

Comment: @dxiv: It should warn for a format string type incompatibility. And it still is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Charles.N `Here is the link` Great. Now all we need is your login credentials. `My debugger doesn't work` Then I seriously suggest you fix whatever broke your debugger, first.

Comment: Thanks Olaf i have changed that specifier.

Comment: How can i attach the text file so you guys can download and use it for testing.

Comment: Here is the link to see the input. Ignore the first one i sent. http://asikpo.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca/Uj/

Comment: @Charles.N The link you just posted goes to an `html` rendition of the text file. If there is any issue with the original file itself (hidden characters, line endings etc) then that would be lost in translation. Besides, you have not answered @paxdiablo's comment below, yet, so the incentive for anyone to debug for you must be pretty low at this point.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but if the file could not be opened, you should exit the program right after the `printf`.

Comment: i have added a return value in my original code. Thank is no longer a problem @ Michael Walz

Answer (score 3):

That code *should* work fine as is, leading me to believe that maybe it's the *file* at issue<sup>(a)</sup>.

For a start, make sure that you *are* reading the file you think you're reading by temporarily renaming it and making sure your code outputs an error. You should also `return 1` if the file cannot be opened so as to not call `fscanf` with a null pointer, and `fclose` the file once you're done with it.

If you don't see the error when you've renamed the file, it may be that your code is running in a different directory than you think it is (some IDEs do this) and there's a file in there that's different from what you expect.

Another possibility is that there's something *within* the file which is causing an issue.

This sort of problem is usually detected by doing a hex dump of the file and ensuring all characters are valid. Under Linux, you could do:

```
od -xcb addresses.txt | less
```

and basically look for any character that's neither `0` through `9` nor a newline `\n`.

If it turns out the file *is* okay, I hesitate to mention this but it *could* be simply because your terminal window or scrollback buffer isn't large enough to hold all the output.

By that I mean, if you have fifty lines in the input file and only forty lines in the terminal window, it may well look to the uninitiated that it starts partway through the data.

Even assuming you're not novice enough to fall for *that,* a 1000-line scrollback buffer with 1010 lines of output could have the same effect.

The best way to check for this is to pipe your program output through `less` so that it shows you a page at a time, or redirect it to a file which you can then view in an editor.

---

For what it's worth, this is how I would have written the code, a minimalist approach which still runs correctly in the absence of the input file and which explicitly cleans up all resources before exit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int LogicalAdd;

    FILE *fp = fopen ("addresses.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error: couldn't open file");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &LogicalAdd) == 1){
        printf ("%u\n", LogicalAdd);
    }

    fclose (fp);
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In fact, despite the minor issues, it *does* work, once you add the correct headers which I assume you just left out of the question. The following transcript shows both the code (header inclusion followed by *exactly* what you had):

```
pax> cat testprog.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char FileName[100];
    unsigned int LogicalAdd;
    FILE *fp; // file pointer
    unsigned int Offset;
    int AmountRead = 0;
    int FirstTime =0;

    fp = fopen("addresses.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL){
            printf("Error: couldn't open file");
    }

    while((fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &LogicalAdd)) == 1){
            printf("%d\n", LogicalAdd);
    }       
}
```

and the output when compiled and run:

```
pax> gcc -o testprog testprog.c ; ./testprog 
16916
62493
30198
53683
40185
28781
24462
48399
64815
18295
12218
22760
57982
27966
54894
38929
```

Comment: Hi Paxdiablo, It works fine. It reads from the correct file. i got an error when i typed in another name for the file.

Comment: @Charles, that wasn't what I suggested and won't show up the problem I posited. You should use the same filename in the code and rename the file you're trying to use.

Comment: if i could attach the original file. so you guys use it to see what issue i am having

Comment: Hey Paxdiablo, try your program with the inputs from the link i provided.

Comment: @Charles.N, it works fine with the data you posted on that link as well. I captured the output and diff'ed it with the original, all numbers were identical. The real question now is: what do *you* see when you run my code?

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem had to do with the console window i was using to display the output. the buffer size of the console window was way smaller than the number of integers i was reading.